# common oracle procedure to call other procedures for sorting, paging and filtering

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have multiple stored procedures in oracle 10g and I want to achieve sorting, paging and filtering without touching them.

I am thinking to have a single common procedure to which I will pass on the sort direction, sorting column, page index, and filter clause along with target procedure and required parameters to it.

This common procedure will execute and return the rows inside it and apply the required filtering, sorting and paging that I want.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Comment: By what method do your procedures return rows?

Comment: What's keeping you from using order by, where and case-when?

Comment: I need to modify all those existing procedure which are quiet complex to modify

Comment: @ANILMANE:Are you allowed to touch the existing code.Or you have been asked to play with the result of the procedure .If you are allowed to change the code ,go and paste your query here ,otherwise ,you can do filtering ,sorting and pagination from the result but that's not the efficient way .

Comment: Can you post the prototypes of the routines you're going to call?

Comment: I have web grids where I need to sort, filter and page by calling existing stored procedures. So  rather changing all existing procedures, i would prefer to create one common procedure for accepting existing procs output and play with it

Comment: @ANILMANE:please confirm my answer ,can you able to visualize your situation with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a package which returns the `employee data` as show below :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE get_data
IS 
TYPE emp_data IS REF CURSOR;

PROCEDURE get_emp_data(p_emp_data IN OUT emp_data);

END get_data;
/

create or replace package body get_data
IS 

PROCEDURE get_emp_data(p_emp_data IN OUT emp_data)
IS

begin

open p_emp_data for select empno
                          ,ename
                          ,job
                          ,mgr
                          ,hiredate
                          ,sal
                          ,comm
                          ,deptno 
                    from   emp;

end get_emp_data;

end get_data;
/
```

Now i am supposing that you are getting the cursor from the procedure `get_data.get_emp_data(..)`.You need to write a procedure that call the above procedure and do `sorting,pagination and filtering` on the above data returned from the cursor.

Here i have considered that you know the columns returned from the above cursor .
Now i will create and object of the columns returned from the proc and the type of that object.

```
create or replace type emp_obj as object 
(
 empno number(4)
,ename varchar2(10)
,job varchar2(9)
,mgr number(4)
,hiredate date
,sal number(7,2)
,comm number(7,2)
,deptno number(2)
);

create type emp_data_nt as table of emp_obj;
```

Now ,the main question ,you want to do sorting as well as pagination on the data from the emp cursor from the existing procedure .
For eg: You need to `order by hiredate` and pick the only 5 records .

Create a procedure that will call the above package procedure

```
create or replace procedure get_emp_data1
(
 v_emp_data IN OUT get_data.emp_data
)
is
v_emp_data_nt emp_data_nt:=emp_data_nt();
v_emp_data_rec emp%ROWTYPE;
i integer :=1;
begin

get_data.get_emp_data(v_emp_data);
LOOP
  FETCH v_emp_data INTO v_emp_data_rec;
  EXIT WHEN v_emp_data%NOTFOUND;
  v_emp_data_nt.extend();

  v_emp_data_nt(i) := emp_obj(v_emp_data_rec.empno
                             ,v_emp_data_rec.ename
                             ,v_emp_data_rec.job  
                             ,v_emp_data_rec.mgr
                             ,v_emp_data_rec.hiredate
                             ,v_emp_data_rec.sal
                             ,v_emp_data_rec.comm
                             ,v_emp_data_rec.deptno);
 i:=i+1;
END LOOP;
close v_emp_data;

open v_emp_data for select * 
                     from (select * from table(v_emp_data_nt) ed 
                            order by ed.hiredate) 
                    where rownum<=5;


end;
```

If i execute the above procedure ,i will get the following output

```
 EMPNO      ENAME   JOB        MGR   HIREDATE       SAL     COMM    DEPTNO
 ===========================================================================
 7369   SMITH   CLERK     7902  17-12-1980  800     20
 7499   ALLEN   SALESMAN  7698  20-02-1981  1600    300 30
 7521   WARD    SALESMAN  7698  22-02-1981  1250    500 30
 7566   JONES   MANAGER   7839  02-04-1981  2975        20
 7698   BLAKE   MANAGER   7839  01-05-1981  2850        30
```

Probably this is not the efficient method,but yes with this way you'll achieve what you want .
I know there are many suggestion from the expert out here ,they are always welcome :)